# Laravel 4: Count relationship within whereHas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 tables as below:

`Subscription` table have a `entrance_limit` column, and it has a `hasMany('Attendance')` relationship. The `entrance_limit` column will actually limit the number of rows in `Attendance`. For example, if the `entrance_limit` value is 10, then we only can create 10 rows in `Attendance`.

`Attendance` table has a `belongsTo('Subscription')` relationship.

How do I get the list of `Subscription` that have total number of `Attendance` less than the `entrance_limit` value?

```
Subscription::whereHas('attendances', function($q) {
    ## something like this
    $q->count() < subscription->entrance_limit
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to get it working with the following:

```
Subscription::whereRaw('
    (select count(*) from `attendances` where `attendances`.`subscription_id` = `subscriptions`.`id`) < `subscriptions`.`entrance_limit`
');
```

Answer (score 0):

Model your query has below

```
Subscription::whereHas('attendances', function($q) {
    $q->where('entrance_limit','>',$q->count());
})
```